# Confused about the boundary settings in developing the transpose of $d/dt$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The goal is to develop the transpose of a derivative operator by using the inner product rule.

$$ 
(Df, g) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (f^{\prime \prime} + B f^{\prime} + Cf)g(t)dt = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(t) (g^{\prime \prime} - B g^{\prime} + Cg)dt = (f, D^{T} g)
$$

The conclusion is
$$
D = \frac{d^2}{dt^2} + B \frac{d}{dt} +C 
$$
leads to
$$
D^T = \frac{d^2}{dt^2} - B \frac{d}{dt} +C 
$$
I cannot get the $\int f^{\prime}g = - \int f g^{\prime}$ and $\int f^{\prime\prime}g = \int f g^{\prime\prime}$. It looks like integration by parts gives the results. However, why did terms $fg$ and $f^{\prime} g - f g ^{\prime}$ vanished? Do I miss any conventional boundary settings in ODE? Can anyone please help? Thanks.